# How to follow Android NFC service and "thin client" with API < 19

Tags: android, nfc

With Android NFC service and "thin client": one problem, and one hack in http://www.dematte.org/2014/08/15/AndroidNFCServiceAndThinClientOneProblemAndOneHack.aspx 
Anyone know how to get reflection of NativeNfcTag and follow testing with that tutorial? Please help me. 
 Thanks